# illegal start of type with catch

Tags: java

So i am writing some code for a rss program and i can't find the problem in my code. i have 4 problems and when i look at the video i was following it looks the exact same. please help me. Thank you in advance. Here are the errors,

```
Main.java:27: error: illegal start of type
    } catch (MalformedURLException ue) {
      ^
Main.java:29: error: illegal start of type
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ^
Main.java:32: error: illegal start of type
    return null;
    ^
Main.java:32: error: ';' expected
    return null;
          ^
Main.java:35: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
5 errors
```

I have researched on stack over flow on several different threads but none of the information helped. I removed curly brackets, added them, added semi-colons, Nothing worked

```
     import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class RSSReader {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printIn(ReadRSS("https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/newtojava/overview/index.html/pageslug?format=rss"));

    }

    public static String readRSS(String urlAddress) {

       URL rssUrl = new URL(urlAddress);
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rssUrl.openStream()));
       String sourceCode = "";
       String line;
       while((line = in.readLine())!=null) {
           if (line.contains("<title>")) {
               int firstPos = line.indexOf("<title>");
               String temp = line.substring(firstPos);
               temp = temp.replace("<title>", "");
               int lastPos = temp.indexOf("</title>");
               temp = temp.substring(0, lastPos);
               sourceCode += temp+"\n";
           }
       }
       in.close();
      return sourceCode;
    } catch (MalformedURLException ue) {
        System.out.printIn("Malformed URL");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.printIn("Something went wrong reading the contents");
    }
    return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, this error means that you have a misplaced closing brace `}`. In this case, you are missing a `try {` (note the opening brace) to go along with the `catch`es.

Comment: plus there's an extra curly bracket at the end

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I see the correct number of closing curly braces if the `try {` is added correctly.

Comment: I know, I thought I'd mention that just in case they add the try with two curly brackets and still end up with an extra one in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Missing try {

and `System.out.printIn` wrong it should be `System.out.println`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RSSReader {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printIn(
                ReadRSS("https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/newtojava/overview/index.html/pageslug?format=rss"));

    }

    public static String readRSS(String urlAddress) {
        try {
            URL rssUrl = new URL(urlAddress);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rssUrl.openStream()));
            String sourceCode = "";
            String line;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("<title>")) {
                    int firstPos = line.indexOf("<title>");
                    String temp = line.substring(firstPos);
                    temp = temp.replace("<title>", "");
                    int lastPos = temp.indexOf("</title>");
                    temp = temp.substring(0, lastPos);
                    sourceCode += temp + "\n";
                }
            }
            in.close();
            return sourceCode;
        } catch (MalformedURLException ue) {
            System.out.println("Malformed URL");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong reading the contents");
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Comment: good catch on the system.out..